# How to upgrade iptables version with apt

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, iptables

My `iptables` version is `v1.6.1`. How can I upgrade it?
I tried:

```
root@ubuntu:~# apt update iptables
E: The update command takes no arguments

root@ubuntu:~#b apt upgrade iptables
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
iptables is already the newest version (1.6.1-2ubuntu2).
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libshishi0 linux-aws-5.4-headers-5.4.0-1037 linux-aws-5.4-headers-5.4.0-1038 linux-aws-5.4-headers-5.4.0-1039
  linux-aws-5.4-headers-5.4.0-1041 linux-aws-5.4-headers-5.4.0-1043 linux-aws-5.4-headers-5.4.0-1045
  linux-aws-5.4-headers-5.4.0-1047 linux-aws-5.4-headers-5.4.0-1048 shishi-common tcpd
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  docker-ce
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

But after that, I checked the version and it still `v1.6.1`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)